# Property '...' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

The error:

```
src/app/AppConfig/appconfig.service.ts: Property 'apiEndpoint' does not exist on type '{}'
```

All of the code looks to be correct, particularly that I get autocomplete that shows `apiEndpoint` correctly.

Not understanding why the error mentions "... not exist on type '{}'". Not sure why an empty object is showing up instead of a type.

I've tried restarting the app (`ng serve -o`), as well as restarting the TS server (using VS Code). Error doesn't go away.

Here's some code:

apiconfig.service.ts:

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
import { AppConfig } from "./appconfig.interface";

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export const APP_SERVICE_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');

export const APP_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: environment.apiEndpoint  // <<< THIS AUTOCOMPLETES AS EXPECTED
}
```

apiconfig.interface.ts

```
export interface AppConfig {
  apiEndpoint: string;
}
```

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiEndpoint: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/",
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I am using Angular 16.

Comment: Do you have multiple variants of `environment.ts` (ie for production, testing, development ...) and during the build you include the correct one based on the configuration? Do all of these different files have the `apiEndpoint` property?

Comment: There are two files:
- environment.ts
- environment.prod.ts

They both have 'apiEndpoint' property.

I have no good answer for "...during the build you include the correct one based on the configuration?". 

Still learning my way around Angular, so I'm not sure where / how to select the correct one during the build.

Comment: he's referring to your configurations in your angular.json (or project.json). See [onfigure-target-specific-file-replacements](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who replied to / commented on this question. The solution in this case is / was:

- Create an 'environment.development.ts' file
- Add the 'apiEndpoint' to this file

Something simple but unknown to me, as I am still working my way through learning Angular.